# Add AND condition in Handlebars/HtmlBars template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, htmlbars

In my Ember project, I have a button as below;

```
{{my-button label="Add"  enabled=(lt gridItems.length maxRecordsInGrid)}}
```

Currently I have the "enabled" property based on gridItems.length < maxRecordsInGrid
I want to add a 2nd condition to this i.e. if a property called "enableBtn" is true

So, essentially, I want the "enabled" property to be an AND between;

1. gridItems.length < maxRecordsInGrid
2. enableBtn is true

Is it possible to do this directly in the template using some inbuilt HTMLBars condition without the need of explicit helpers?

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible in ember itself.

You can use [`ember-truth-helpers`](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers) for this.

There is an [open RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/562) to add this to ember itself.